# valgrind Address is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

I'm working on a math library.

*create_vector* create a vector of dimension n: (v1, v2, v3, ..., vn)

*delete_vector* free the memory.

```
struct Vector
{
    unsigned int dimension;
    double *components;
};
typedef struct Vector *vector_t;

vector_t create_vector(const unsigned int dimension)
{
    if(!dimension)
        return NULL;

    vector_t vector = (vector_t)malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));
    vector->dimension = dimension;
    vector->components = (double *)calloc(dimension, sizeof(double));

    return vector;
}

void delete_vector(vector_t *vector)
{
    if(*vector == NULL)
        return;

    free((*vector)->components);
    free(*vector);
    *vector = NULL;
}
```

Main file:

```
int main()
{
    vector_t vector1 = create_vector(3);
    delete_vector(&vector1);
}
```

In main file, I use this two functions, but valgrind gives me these warnings. There isn't any memory leaks. How can i solve?

```
==6906== Invalid write of size 4
==6906==    at 0x108800: create_vector (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==    by 0x10877E: main (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==  Address 0x4b3702c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==6906==    at 0x483021B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==6906==    by 0x1087DC: create_vector (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==    by 0x10877E: main (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==
==6906== Invalid read of size 4
==6906==    at 0x10882B: delete_vector (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==    by 0x108790: main (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==  Address 0x4b3702c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==6906==    at 0x483021B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==6906==    by 0x1087DC: create_vector (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==    by 0x10877E: main (in /home/mrcoder/Scrivania/GitHub/libmath/test/testvector)
==6906==
==6906==
==6906== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6906==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6906==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 28 bytes allocated
==6906==
==6906== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6906==
==6906== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6906== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: If I compile and execute your program under _valgring_ I do not have error/warning. Please compile your program with the debug (option -g) to see where _valgrind_ signals a problem, even it will probably `vector->dimension = dimension;` and `vector->dimension = dimension;`

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a `typedef` alias, such as `vector_t`.  Doing so usually confuses much more than it helps.

Comment: So i have:
*libvector.h* (Header file)

*libvector.c* (Library file)

*main.c* (Main file)

I tried and if I declare these functions in *main.c* file there is no warning. Why?

Comment: The code presented does not reproduce the problem for me, nor do I see any reason to think that it produces the problem for *you*.  @bruno's guess as to the nature of the problem in your real code is plausible, but it is impossible to write an answer to the question, as presently posed, that is both helpful to you and objectively correct.

Comment: First, I see no `#include` statements.  Make sure all the proper header files for the functions your are calling are `#include`'d.  Second, you do not show your `libvector.h` header file.  Show that.  Third, how are you compiling your code?  You should turn on all warnings.

Comment: @AndrewHenle he gives the _Vector_definition, putting all in a unique file it is just needed to add a `#include <stdlib.h>` to be able to compile

Comment: @bruno The example isn't **complete**.  I've learned (mostly the hard way...) not to guess at answers given incomplete information, especially when complete information could easily be provided just by asking.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am probably too gentle yes (if a colleague reads that he will ask why I am not at work)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you do not compiled with `malloc(sizeof(vector_t));` rather than with `malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));` ?

*block of size 4 alloc'd* indicates you *malloc* only 4 bytes being the size of a pointer if you have a 32b CPU, the size of the struct is minimum 8 bytes

Comment: This is does not answer the question.  Did you intend to write it as a comment, instead?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think this answers the question, I mean I think he compiled with `malloc(sizeof(vector_t))` ;-)

Comment: If you think that, then the answer would be improved by saying so directly.  But even then, if your conclusion is that the code presented in the question does not reproduce the issue then the correct response is either to ask for clarification *in comments* or to vote to close the question as not reproducible.

Comment: @JohnBollinger as you can see I am french, my English is not perfect, I just try to help him, and I am afraid to vote to close will not help him :-)

Comment: In a case such as this, VTC + comment helps not only the OP, but also everyone else.  Plus, it also covers *you* in the event that the error in the OP's code turns out to be different than you suppose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't have your experience, I just follow my feeling to try help him, also hoping he will reacts to know if my hypothesis is true or false. Of course if you think I am wrong and VTC + comment is a better way just do it

Comment: And I did VTC + comment.  But I also consider it part of my civic duty to try to train those with less experience in our community conventions and norms.  That there is a standard close reason that fits this question perfectly (and another, no MCVE, that also fits it well) should be taken as an indication that closing such questions is the appropriate behavior, until and unless they are improved.  But I will say no more on this topic here.  Ultimately, it is also part of our culture that you may largely do as you please with the privileges afforded you.

Answer (score 0):

You have `vector_t` `typedef`'d to be a `struct Vector *`, so `sizeof(vector_t)` effectively expands to `sizeof(struct Vector *)`. All pointers are the same size, either 4 or 8 whenever working on modern hardware, so you're not really getting the size of the struct, but the size of a pointer to your struct.

Instead you should do `malloc(sizeof(struct Vector))` to get enough space for your structure.